# Modifying public disk url - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to achieve two things within my Laravel `5.8` project:

First of all, add the next variable on my `.env` file:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

And finally, modify my public disk url from this:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
```

To this:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/api/storage',
```

Either way, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is it the `.env` variable or I can't do such thing as modify the disk url?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. To modify the default file system, set the `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` in your `.env` file:

**.env**

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Then in your `config/filesystems.php`, to modify the url do this:

**config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

    ...

    'public' => [
        ...

        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/api/storage',

        ...
    ],

    ...
],
```

Do not forget to clear your config cache after doing this changes:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: By doing so, I should get a file at my storage within this link: ``http://localhost:8000/api/storage/file.extension`` ? Because that's what I want but it does not work. It keeps retrieving the file but only if I remove the ``/api/`` from the URL.

Comment: Note: I used that last command that you pointed out but it keeps doing the same thing.

Comment: How are you getting the `url`?

Comment: I'm putting it directly on my get method (I am using axios)

Comment: But how, are you using `url(...)`/`asset()` or just query from db?

Comment: Like this: ``this.$http.get(this.providerCsvUrl).then(...).catch(...);`` where ``this.providerCsvUrl`` value is: ``/api/storage/csv/csv_proveedor_1.csv``